# I'm trying to insert an intro video into homepage of my dash app, unsuccessfully

Tags: python, html, video, plotly-dash

I'm trying to insert an intro video into the homepage of my dash app, unsuccessfully.  There is no error, the app is loading but there is only a blank page showing up. What am I doing wrong?

```
from dash import html
from navbar import create_navbar

nav = create_navbar()


header = html.A(html.Video(src='intro.mp4'))


def create_page_home():
    layout = html.Div([
        nav,
        header,
    ])
    return layout
```

Answer (score 0):

You create an object `app` and set the layout like that:

```
from dash import Dash, html


app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Nav(html.Video(
            controls = True,
            src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
        ))
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```